# WPF RibbonButton multiline text

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon-button

I have a WPF application. I am using .NET 6.

I need to have two lines of text in my `RibbonButton` control.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="rbName" 
            LargeImageSource="../Resources/broom-3w.png"
            ToolTip="{Binding RibBtnToolTip}" 
            Command="{Binding RibBtnCommand}" 
            Label  ="{Binding LblContent}"> 
</RibbonButton>
```

This displays the text however it is not formatted correctly for me.
The text breaks however it is not consistent across all `RibbonButton`, i.e. it doesn't always break where I need it to.
Also the text is center aligned.

I've tried putting '\n' in the label string but it won't display any text after the '\n'.

I have tried to add a `StackPanel` and two `TextBlock`.
There is no compile error in doing this, however no text displays at all, just the image.

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="rbName" 
            LargeImageSource="../Image.png"  
            ToolTip="{Binding RibBtnToolTip}"  
            Command="{Binding RibBtnCommand}">
    <RibbonButton.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lbl1}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lbl2}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </RibbonButton.Content>
</RibbonButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RibbonButton` control uses an [RibbonTwoLineText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontwolinetext?view=windowsdesktop-8.0?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to display the text. The `HorizontalAlignment` property of this one is set (hardcoded) to `Center` in the default template. To change it, you can either define your own custom template or set the property dynamically at runtime. You may also want to decrease the `LineHeight` property which is set to `13` by default:

```
private void rbName_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender;
    RibbonTwoLineText text = btn.Template.FindName("TwoLineText", btn) as RibbonTwoLineText;
    if (text != null)
    {
        text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        text.LineHeight = 8;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="rbName" Loaded="rbName_Loaded" LargeImageSource="..." />
```

By default, the `LargeImageSource` is 32x32 in size and the total height of the `RibbonButton` control is 66.